# How to make multiple systemd services start/stop as a group?

Tags: systemd, services

In *Linux*, regarding *systemd*:  How do you make a service that starts a bunch of other services?  ...acting like a container or group or parent.

I have 5 or so *systemd* services:

- `app.alpha.service`
- `app.bravo.service`
- `app.charlie.service`
- `app.delta.service`
- `app.echo.service`

And they are each part of an `app` uber-service, which I have not been able to successfully create a `.service` file for.

I would like to be able to start/stop them all together as a group.

e.g.:

```
sudo systemctl start app
```

I did this by creating an `app.service` like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Service
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And in each `app.*.service` file it names `app.service` with a `PartOf`:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=app.service
```

It seems like this isn't enough and I haven't set this up correctly yet.  How do I do this?

Also, the `app.service` doesn't really do anything.  It's just intended to be a logical container.  Not sure if that's allowed or not.

Comment: Can they run individually, and do you want to be able to support that? Otherwise, consider one service that starts & stops multiple processes.

Comment: But consider it from a long way off.  Like one does with fireworks.  http://jdebp.uk./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/two-services.html

Comment: Yes they run individually.  And it makes sense to shut down some parts without others.  There's a modest wide tree of dependencies with the group. 
 But during maintenance, they all need to be shut down together.

Comment: I asked because of your statement that you'd like to start & stop them together. Would you consider a simple shell script that called 'systemctl start' or 'systemctl stop' on each service?

Comment: You could just use Requires= or BindsTo= and After= lists.  I think PartOf may do the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 7):

I've found something that is working for me.

This change to *app.service* makes it so that when you **start** app.service, the others will start too.  Name the other services with `Wants=`

#### app.service:

```
[Unit]
Wants=app.alpha.service
Wants=app.bravo.service
Wants=app.charlie.service
Wants=app.delta.service
Wants=app.echo.service
```

This change to the individual services makes it so that when you **stop** app.service the others this service will stop too.  Name the controlling service with `PartOf=`

#### app.*.service:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=app.service
```

I don't like that I have to change both .service files, but this is sufficient to unblock me.

Comment: I think you also need ExecStart in Service of app.service. Since it does directly do anything, I used ExecStart=/bin/true & RemainAfterExit=yes. Additionally, I had After in addition to Wants.